# Assembly to compare three digits to register without considering the lsb

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tic-tac-toe

I made a Tic-Tac-Toe in Assembly 8086, I have Just one problem how I check if X won, I need just compare a register to all the winning options, the options are three digits but what if X moved 4 times, I need to check if the register contains those three digit options without considering the fourth digit in the register. I would appreciate some help please.

Comment: Try something like if `(reg AND mask) == mask`, i.e. are all bits in `mask` also set in `reg`?

Comment: How are you representing the board state in a register?  With a bit-board of move positions, with a set bit for every square where this side has made a move?  When you say "digit", do you mean *binary* digit, i.e. set bit?

Comment: With move positions, when I say digit I mean hexadecimal digits, and they are in the memory but I order them in a register for the check by size.